# Function to convert float to an ljust string

Tags: python-3.x

I find myself for a certain program, doing this a lot:

```
val="%.1f" % num
val=str(val).ljust(8)
```

The result is I take a number like .12345678 and return something like "       .1" for pretty formatting.

I'd like to do this in a function like

```
def floatToString(num,numDigits,length):
```

However, I am having trouble with the "%.numDigits".

Help?

Comment: ```str(num)[1:3]```?

Comment: sometimes the number could be 2.34567. Looking for 3 decimal places.

Comment: so from ```2.34567``` you want ```'.345'```?

Answer (score 0):

New style formatting can handle dynamic parameters.

```py
def floatToString(num, numDigits, length):
    return f'{num:<{length}.{numDigits}f}'
```

Comment: How does one rjust? Synatx isn't clear to me yet.

Comment: To get rjust, replace `<` with `>`.  [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info) explains them pretty well.